# Debugging coroutines using gdb

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, c++20

I'm using gdb 11.1 to debug a program using coroutines compiled with gcc 11.1

Putting a breakpoint inside a coroutine is not working well, GDB jumps directly to the end of the block.

With the CTRL+X+A, the debugger arrow is shown at the start, then the end of the coroutine.

Is there a workaround for this or gdb is not fully supporting coroutines?

Comment: Update: If compiled -O0 I can debug but not with -Og as expected. You may fill bug reports for gcc and gdb, but as -O0 works, it might be ok.

Comment: Have same problems, seem gcc not ready for coroutines. Try print for debug..